# Accessibility services get disabled automatically

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, accessibility

This Christmas I gave a **Wiko Lenny 3** to my son, it comes with Marshmallow.
When trying to install a parental control I sadly discovered that there's a bug (I suppose) that is well documented for Lollipop/Samsung, that prevents **accessibility services** to be activated.

In other words, as soon as I activate the parental control in the settings/accessibility/services option, it always appears off, although it's on, and resets to off randomly and at every reboot. This makes totally unusable the parental control.

The questions are:

- is there a fix for this? (Any solution with battery savings was tested with no success)
- is there a way to **understand**, via logs or monitorings, what is preventing the services to be activated?
- would rooting some how change something?
- is it safe or even possible to install a different and clean Android version?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the launch setting to start manually and not automatically seems to work.

In Huawei devices, it can be found in **Apps - *app name* - Battery - Launch**.

[image: "Launch" option on Huawei device]

Battery saving options, on the other hand, didn't help in my case.