# MacroDroid asks for "Application Launched/Closed" accessibility permission constantly

Tags: settings, accessibility, macrodroid

I'm on non-rooted Android 8.1 Oreo with MacroDroid Pro v3.24.1. After I got a replacement phone and reinstalled MacroDroid, it constantly asks for accessibility permission: Application Launched/Closed.

There are three accessibility permissions available:

- MacroDroid
- MacroDroid Fingerprint Gesture Detector
- MacroDroid Volume Button Monitor

I enabled the first and last and kept the fingerprint off as this disables drawer swiping. I don't get where to allow that accessibility permission it is asking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an avid user of MacroDroid and noticed this issue with two devices and raised this issue on app forums (accessible from within the device and my post dated 24 December 17- unable to link)

This is what the developer said

> It's not a MacroDroid issue but a system issue that can happen with any app.
>
> If you Google the issue you will find stuff like this:
> [Accessibility services gets disabled automatically](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137195/131553)

I find this to be true, since I had this problem on stock ROM but not on custom ROM

Quite possibly same case with you

Comment: So what is the full link ? (currently badly formatted and can't be followed ...)

Comment: Judging from the last word and the context, it might be [Accessibility services gets disabled automatically](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137195/44325) or [Accessibility services get disabled automatically](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/165550/44325)

Comment: Thanks Andrew//@SRG..sorry for delayed response. Did not see your comment earlier. Fixed